# Quran verses on achievements and pay gratitude to Allah

Tags: quran, verses

Aslam o Alaikum. I would like to know the Quran verses that I can recite in my new office start celebration ceremony. I m looking for the verses that has some meaning to “thanks to Allah on some achievements”. Or these may be that “thank you Allah for giving us all the blessings.”. I m going to recite these verses before the whole staff.

Thanks in advance. Jazak Allah